# write a value of some key from a dictionary if it doesn't exist in the file

Tags: python

So this script below looks for keywords from the file `index.html` and writes the values of those keywords in a different file `style.css`.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

    keyword = {
    "row": '''
    .row {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex; 
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    }'''
    #etc
        }   

with open('index.html', 'r') as file:
   with open('style.css', 'a') as newfile:
      lines = file.readlines()
      for line in lines:
         if 'class="' in line:
            to_replace = line.split('"')[1].split()
            to_replace = OrderedDict.fromkeys(to_replace)
            for key in to_replace:
                if key in keyword:
                    newfile.write(keyword[key])
                    keyword[key] = ''
```

the HTML file:

```
<div class="row"></div> etc
```

but there's a problem. when i run the script N times, it should output the value only once in `style.css`:

```
.row {
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex; 
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin-right: -15px;
        margin-left: -15px;
        }
```

in my case it writes the value of 'row' **as many times as** i run the script.

> how do i prevent the value duplication?

I've tried to do something, but it doesn't work:

```
with open('index.html', 'r') as file:
  to_read = open('style.css')
  to_write = open('style.css', 'a')
  lines = file.readlines()
  for line in lines:
     if 'class="' in line:
        to_replace = line.split('"')[1].split()
        to_replace = OrderedDict.fromkeys(to_replace)
        for key in to_replace:
          if key in keyword:
            if key in to_read.read():
              break
            else:
              to_write.write(keyword[key])         
              keyword[key] = ''
```

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question directly and I can see how that would be annoying but I strongly recommend replacing all of this with code built on a library that parses the HTML properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when i run the script N times, it should output the value only once in `style.css`

Why? You open the file `style.css` in *append* mode so everytime the script is run the output is appended to the output of previous runs.

If you only want to keep the result of the last run, the answer is trivial: just open the file in erase mode:

```
    with open('style.css', 'w') as newfile:
```

If you want to keep unique outputs from many runs (using different files), you will have to use an auxilliary file to keep track of what keys were used to feed the file. For example you could use a json file to keep the current value of the keyword dict:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from json import load, dump, JSONDecodeError

keywordfile = "keyword.json"

try:
    with open(keywordfile) as fd:  # try to load keyword from a previous invocation
        keyword = load(fd)
except (FileNotFoundError, JSONDecodeError):
        keyword = {                # initialize it if unavailable
"row": '''
.row {
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex; 
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
margin-right: -15px;
margin-left: -15px;
}'''
#etc
        }   

# normal processing
with open('index.html', 'r') as file:
   with open('style.css', 'a') as newfile:
       ...

# save keyword for following invocations    
with open(keywordfile, 'w') as fd:
    dump(keyword, fd)
```

Comment: hi! thanks for the answer! I've tried this but it gives an error: `ImportError: cannot import name JSONDecodeError`. what do I do?

Comment: The second part of the answer uses append mode. The problem is that you are an intelligent human being, able to remember what you have just done. But a script is just a dumb piece of code that cannot know what it has done in previous invocations except if it was saved on permanent memory (ie disk).

Comment: thanks man, it did work after all:D I just updated my python.

Answer (score 1):

That happens because you open `style.css` file in `append` mode (`open('style.css', 'a')`). That means that every time that you open that file, it will just continue writing on the first blank line. Instead, what you want to do is use `'w+'` mode which will create the file if it's not already there and write inside. The next time you run this, it will wipe the file clean and start writing from the start, like you just created it.

So, instead of `open('style.css', 'a')` use `open('style.css', 'w+')` and your problem is solved.

**EDIT**

For using different file names, just pick a base name for your file, like `style.css`. What we'll do is append a number to each of the files based on the files in the directory. Then before saving the file just check out the directory where you want the file to be saved with `os.listdir()` and see what files are there. Let's say you ran the script 3 times. There will be `[style_1.css, style_2.css, style_0.css]`. Now you can sort them to get `[style_0.css, style_1.css, style_2.css]` and tahe the last one with `files_list[-1]`. Split by `'.'` and then by `'_'` to get a number and then just increment it. I will show you the code for so it's easier to understand:

```
filename = sorted(os.listdir(dir_to_css_files))[-1]
number = filename.split('.')[0].split('_')[-1]
n = str(int(number) + 1)
new_file = 'style_ + number + '.css'
```

**Using python structures**

I'm not sure what you're doing but this is the way of waiting the script to finish, populate the dictionary with desired values and then saving it to the file. If you run the script again, it will wipe that file and save the new values to the same filename.

```
d = dict()

with open('index.html', 'r') as file:
  lines = file.readlines()
  for line in lines:
     if 'class="' in line:
        to_replace = line.split('"')[1].split()
        to_replace = OrderedDict.fromkeys(to_replace)
        for key in to_replace:
            if key in keyword:
                d[key] = keyword[key]
                keyword[key] = ''

  with open ('style.css', 'w+') as new_file:
    new_file.write(str(d))
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I do need it to append, not write

Comment: you can then use different files in each run of the script... Or, just collect all the data you need to write in some python structure: `dict` or `list` and then just write it once. There is no other solution

Comment: ow, I swear I have been trying to do what you said but I couldn't figure out how. can you show me real quick?

Comment: Do you mean the one with different filenames or using the python structure?

Comment: oh sorry, I meant the second one. Using different files seems not very convenient if I properly get what you meant by that.. 

Comment: I've updated the post with different files approach. See if that works for you and I'll try to add file structures...

Comment: wow, I really appreciate your help! I didn't quite get the different files approach. what if I keep the program running in the background? do I create infinite files or what? 
I tried to run the second one, it does the same thing as my initial code but writes the values all in one single line which is weird. how does it work for you? are you sure it is correct?

Comment: Isn't there really any other way NOT to write a line if it already exists? why can't it be that easy..

Comment: Regarding creating the infinite files, your question was if you run the script several times, the style.css has several appended outputs and the question was how can i stop the appended outputs. You didn't mention that you'd keep the script running.

Comment: If you stop the script and re-run it it will start everything from the beginning. The format of the output is changeable if you want (dump the dict to JSON etc). Another thing you can do is open a file, search for the key or line in it and if there's one, just skip it. But it'll be painfully slow and inefficient.